# How to add nodes in treeview from a list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have following code where I require to create the node and sub node that is to bind with the list. 
I am converting it to array then I am trying to add, but I fail to do this How should I do it? Following is my code:

```
foreach (var item in ProductCategory)
{
    TreeNode tr = new TreeNode(item.CatName);
    List<dataObject> lst = objFreecusatomization.GetAllCustomItems(CategoryType.Dressing, item.CategoryID);
    TreeNode[] sumItemList =new TreeNode[lst.Count];

    foreach (var subItem in lst)
    {
        sumItemList[sumItemList] = new TreeNode { Name = subItem.Name, Text = subItem.Name, Checked = subItem.Selected };
    }

    treeCustomItem.Nodes.Add(item.CatName, sumItemList);
}
```

And I also need to assign key value, name to the items being added. through LinQ or lambda-expression. What's the best way?

Comment: What exactly is failing? What errors are you getting? Or what is happening, that you didn't expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fail: sumItemList[sumItemList] = new TreeNode ... The index of an array cannot be the array itself.

Since you have no indexer (because of the foreach) I suggest you use a List, like this:

```
foreach (var item in ProductCategory)
{
    TreeNode treeCustomItem = new TreeNode(item.CatName);
    List<dataObject> lst = objFreecusatomization.GetAllCustomItems(CategoryType.Dressing, item.CategoryID);
    List<TreeNode> sumItemList = new List<TreeNode>();

    foreach (var subItem in lst)
    {
        sumItemList.Add(new TreeNode { ... });
    }

    treeCustomItem.Nodes.AddRange(sumItemList.ToArray());
}
```

But since you're already iterating over your fetched subitems, you can also add the subitems directly instead of using an array/list. Your inner foreach would become:

```
foreach (var subItem in lst)
{
    treeCustomItem.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { ... });
}
```